# Hyperlink Markdown dynamically in discord

Tags: discord, markdown

I'm trying to make an embed message where the title of the video is the link. To achieve that I'm using square brackets and parentheses around the objects, but they are being shown as strings in the message. Any ideas on how this could be done?

```
for (let i in listaResultados){
    embed.addField(
    `${parseInt(i)+1}: [${listaResultados[i].tituloVideo}](${listaResultados[i].link})`,
     listaResultados[i].descricao)
}
```

Comment: You forgot a bracket, no?

Comment: No, in my code it's like this [${listaResultados[i].tituloVideo}](${listaResultados[i].link})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed field names do not support markdown, including masked links.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I make the title of the video be the link? Because I have seen this in some bots, but couldn't figure out how to do.

Comment: Use the description instead

Answer (score 0):

I think there are couple solutions you can do.

1. Utilize the Embed's title and url properties. However, this would limit you to producing only one embed per video, which means only 10 total (at one time) since 10 is the limit per message.

```
{
  "embed": {
    "title": "Music Video Title",
    "description": "Description goes here",
    "url": "https://video-url.com"
  }
}
```

2. The other way is to do what the other user mentioned - use the description field.

```
{
  "embed": {
    "title": "Music Videos List",
    "description": "1. [Video 1](https://google.com) \n 2. [Video 2](https://google.com/) \n 3. [Video 3](https://google.com/)"
  }
}
```

You can use [this website](https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/) for quick reference and experimentation of the embed code.